# Dynamic Internal Styles not Overwriting External Styles

Tags: html, css

I have linked an external style sheet in my html page using  tag like below,

```
<link href="CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

which has styles,

```
.myDiv{height:200px;}
```

On document read I am creating some styles and append it as internal style sheet in head section like,

```
    var styles = ".mydiv{height:350px; width:300px;}";
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    styleNode = document.createElement("style");
    styleNode.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    styleNode.setAttribute("id", "game_style");
    headID.appendChild(styleNode);

    if (styleNode.styleSheet) {// IE
        styleNode.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
    } else {// the world
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(styles);
        styleNode.appendChild(textNode);
    }
```

the new style width is applied correctly but the height is not reflected on IE8 browsers only. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Which is working fine is local host site but not in live server site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found error in page DOM structure. script tag not closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

what about mentioning the `!important` for height?

```
var styles = ".mydiv{height:350px !important; width:300px;}";
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine.without adding "!important" is works fine in local host not work in live server

Comment: Okay. But you mean even after adding `!important`, it's not working in live server?

Comment: after adding {!important} its working fine in both local and live.